# Ask/command someone to "take this"

Tags: traducción

Say I have my hands full but need to grab something else. In English, I would say "here, take this" or "could you hold this" or "can you take this for a second".

How could I say this in Spanish? To a friend? More politely, to a superior?

"¿Darlo por favor?"
"¿Podría ayudarme para tomar eso?"

Comment: I simply say 'Toma' when I'm in a bind like that.  Typically though, you say 'Toma' right as you are handing something to someone.  I suppose it's the English equivalent of "Here!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not *darlo* nor *tomar*

> ¿Podría **sujetar** esto, por favor?
>
> ¿Podría **cogerme** esto, por favor? (as long as you are not talking to Argentinians)
>
> ¿Podría **sostenerme** esto, por favor?

or even

> ¿Podría **guardarme** esto un momento, por favor?

So my advice is to use the verbs *sujetar, coger, sostener* and *guardar* in that context.

Use *darlo* only to request it back:

> ¿Podrías darmelo de vuelta, por favor?

and instead of *tomar* think of *coger o agarrar* for "take" (Again, carefull with the double meaning of *coger* in certain countries).

Comment: Gracias!! What is the double meaning of coger? Since you say to be careful, I'm assuming it is sexual/rude?

Comment: @RossHamish, Yes, sexual. It stands for the F-word, at least in Argentina, but I'm not sure in which other south-american countries. Definitely, not in Spain. Also, I don't have access to accents with this keyboard. I'll edit my answer to include them later.

Comment: In a place like Mexico, *coger* is exclusively understood as *to fuck*. In Cuba, like in Spain, it's entirely non-vulgar. In other countries, both meanings are prevalent with context distinguishing whether to interpret it as vulgar.

Answer (score 2):

En México diríamos:

> Agárrame esto por favor. *Litteral translation for 'here take this'.*
>
> Agárrame esto tantito por favor. *Here, hold this for a second*.

In both cases you can say "porfa" instead of "por favor"

More polite:

> Disculpe, ¿podría agarrarme ésto por favor? *Talking to elder people*
>
> Disculpa, ¿podrías agarrarme ésto por favor? *Talking to people of your same age, or less than 40*

You can add "oye" in the beggining of these two "Oye disculpa". And you can also say "porfa".

There are other words than *agarrar*, like *sostener* but *agarrar* is the most common here.